# Not storing cell value when other grid row is selected in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3, sencha-cmd

I'm having two grid in application & I'm using rowSelectionModel. Now after user write anything in editable cell & then (w/o clicking anywhere) clicks on main grid row; rowselect function is getting called.

Please tell me way to retain the data in cell ???

```
/*********main tree *************/
var gridtree = new Ext.ux.maximgb.tg.EditorGridPanel({
            id: 'mainTree',
            store: storeCMP,
            autoScroll: true,
            layout: 'fit',
            cm: colModeltree,
            title: 'Text Execution Form',
            master_column_id: 'NAME',
            width: screen.width - 120,
            height: 170,
            columnWidth: 0.1,
            sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({
                singleSelect: true,
                autoExpandColumn: 'NAME',
                listeners: {
                    rowselect: function(sm, row, rec) {
                        renderFloatingArray(); 
                        var sgrid = Ext.getCmp("mainTree");
                        if (rec.data.level === 0) {
                            titlegrid = rec.data.NAME;
                            Ext.getCmp("questionGrid").hide();
                            Ext.getCmp("sampleGrid").hide();
                        } else if (rec.data.level === 1) {
                            titlegrid = rec.data.NAME;
                            Ext.getCmp('sampleGrid').setTitle('Samples for &nbsp;&nbsp;' + titlegrid + '&nbsp;');
                            if (F.TRO_GRC_OBJECT_TYPE.read(1) === "") {
                                filterdataQs(gridStoreQs, rec.data.TST_TEST_EXECUTION_ID, rec.data.TESTING_ID);
                                if (Ext.getCmp('questionGrid').getStore().data.items.length === 0) {
                                    Ext.getCmp("questionGrid").hide();
                                } else {
                                    Ext.getCmp('questionGrid').setTitle('&nbsp;Questions for ' + titlegrid + '&nbsp;');
                                    Ext.getCmp("questionGrid").show();
                                }
                                Ext.getCmp('sampleGrid').setTitle('Samples for ' + titlegrid + '&nbsp;');
                                Ext.getCmp("sampleGrid").show();
                                filterdataQs(gridStoreQs, rec.data.TST_TEST_EXECUTION_ID, rec.data.TESTING_ID);
                                filterdatasample(sampleGridstore, rec.data.TST_TEST_EXECUTION_ID, rec.data.TESTING_ID);
                            } else {
                                Ext.getCmp("questionGrid").hide();
                                Ext.getCmp("sampleGrid").hide();
                            }
                        } else if (rec.data.level == 2) {
                            Ext.getCmp("questionGrid").show();
                            Ext.getCmp("sampleGrid").show();
                            filterdataQs(gridStoreQs, rec.data.TST_TEST_EXECUTION_ID, rec.data.TRID_OBJID_ORG_ID);
                            filterdatasample(sampleGridstore, rec.data.TST_TEST_EXECUTION_ID, rec.data.TRID_OBJID_ORG_ID);
                        }}}}),
            listeners: {
                viewready: function(g) {
             if (F.TRO_GRC_OBJECT_TYPE.read(1) === "") {
                        g.getSelectionModel().selectRow(1);
                    } else {
                        g.getSelectionModel().selectRow(2);
                    }
                },

                'rowcontextmenu': gridContextMenu


            },

            viewConfig: {
                enableRowBody: true


            },

            plugins: [{
                ptype: 'editable-grid'
            }]

        });
```

question - grid

```
var grid2 = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
            id: 'questionGrid', 
            store: gridStoreQs,
            hidden: false,
            layout: 'fit',
            autoScroll: true,
            sm: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({
                singleSelect: true,
                listeners: {
                    rowselect: function(sm, row, rec) {
                        currentgrid = 'questionGrid';}}}),
            width: screen.width - 120,
            autoHeight: true,
            columnLines: true,
            viewConfig: {
            },
            title: 'Question Grid',
            cm: colModelQs,
            enableKeyEvents: true,
            plugins: [{ ptype: 'editable-grid' }],
            onEditComplete: function(ed, value, startValue) {
            if (ed.field.getXType() == "numberfield" || ed.field.getXType() == "textfield") {
                    this.editing = false;
                    this.activeEditor = null;
                    ed.un("specialkey", this.selModel.onEditorKey, this.selModel);
                    var r = ed.record;
                    var field = this.colModel.getDataIndex(ed.col);
                    var e = {
                        grid: this,
                        record: r,
                        field: field,
                        originalValue: startValue,
                        value: value,
                        row: ed.row,
                        column: ed.col,
                        cancel: false
                    };
                    if (this.fireEvent("validateedit", e) !== false && !e.cancel) {
                        r.set(field, value);
                        delete e.cancel;
                        this.fireEvent("afteredit", e);
                    }

                    this.view.focusCell(ed.row, ed.col);
                }
            },
            listeners: {
                'afteredit': afterTreeGridCellEdit
            }
        });
```

plugin used : editable-grid

Comment: could you provide some code or a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

The value is saved into the underlying record on cell editor blur event. Only if the entered value is invalid it is reverted back. So check if you are entering a valid value and if it does not help prepare a showcase on https://fiddle.sencha.com

Comment: Actually completeEdit() is not getting called, as rowselect function gets called. Also, if there is some delay then data gets stored.